# Как загрузить текст из текстового файла в char?

Tags: winforms, c++, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток.

Будьте добры показать, как загрузить текст из текстового файла в массив символов char?

Спасибо.

PS. WinForms, C++, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: А может, лучше использовать string?

Answer (score 1):

Если очень приспичило использовать массив чаров и если использовать только стандартную библиотеку, то можно так

```
ifstream fs ("file.txt");
ostringstream strs;
strs << fs.rdbuf();
size_t len = strs.str().length();
char* a = new char [len + 1];   
strs.str().copy (a, len);
a[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: @mikillskegg, неужели одного ifstream недостаточно ? 

Наверняка у него есть методы, аналогичные fseek(), ftell() и fread().

Comment: Есть, конечно. Вообще, использование char[] в программе на С++ без крайней нужды - не очень хороший стиль.

А вообще, для определения размера файла очень удобно использовать функцию file_size() из Boost.filesystem. Переносимый быстрый способ.

Comment: Ну, stat() IMHO тоже уже везде реализован. Сразу достаете массу обычно ненужной информации. Наверняка Boost его и делает, а потом просто прячет структурку.

Answer (score 0):

Это из той же оперы, что и "Как загрузить текст в Label?"
Если да, то еще раз повторюсь: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52yxde8.aspx) в помощь!
Если нет, то все равно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52yxde8.aspx) в помощь, [Google](http://google.com) тоже знает об [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52yxde8.aspx).

Comment: IMHO лучше использовать posix функции.

Comment: Лучше чем?

Comment: Тем, что быстрее работают, вероятно. Когда требований к быстродействию нет - я думаю, и париться не стоит - пользоваться тем, что обеспечивает более быструю разработку.

Comment: @mikillskegg, лучше, чем MSDN. Переносимостью лучше. В этом же ключе C лучше, чем C++.

Comment: Ну, MSDN я вообще в расчет не беру. Переносимость у стандартных библиотек С++ такая же, как и у сишных. Скорость работы ввода-вывода практически такая же (сам проверял). Зато работать с ними с проще. Единственное преимущество Си в целом - меньший объем получаемых файлов и, соответственно, меньший расход памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Определить размер файла, создать массив достаточной вместимости, открыть файл, прочитать его в массив, закрыть файл.

Определение размера и открытие файла можно совместить.